# MDL - ripple effect changes margin on some elements

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design-lite

I'm using react with mdl and I want to create a menu with a drawer, and I'm pretty happy with the result, except one thing, when there is a scroller on the menu and I click on a menu item there is a ripple effect that sometimes makes the other menu items move a bit:

[image]

I don't know what is going on, here is my menu item component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class MenuItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    }

    onClick() {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.id);
    }

    render () {
        let liClassNames = this.props.isSelected ? 'menuItemSelected' : 'menuItemNotSelected';
        return (
            <div className={'mdl-list__item mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect menuItem ' + liClassNames} onClick={this.onClick}>
                <span className='mdl-list__item-primary-content'>
                    <i className={'material-icons menuItemIcon md-28'}>{this.props.icon}</i>
                    <span>{this.props.screenName}</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

React.propTypes = {
    id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    screenName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    icon: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    isSelected: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    onClick: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Menu:

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem';

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isMaximized: true,
            selectedMenuItem: this.props.modules[0].screens[0].id
        };

        this.handleMenuToggle = this.handleMenuToggle.bind(this);
        this.onMenuItemClick = this.onMenuItemClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleMenuToggle() {
        this.setState({ isMaximized: !this.state.isMaximized });
    }

    onMenuItemClick(screenId) {
        this.setState({ selectedMenuItem: screenId });
    }

    render () {
        let drawerClassNames = this.state.isMaximized ? 'drawerMaximized' : 'drawerMinimized';
        return (
            <div className='mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer'>
                <div className={'mdl-layout__drawer drawer scrollbar ' + drawerClassNames }>
                    <ul className='demo-list-item mdl-list content'>
                    {this.props.modules.map((module, index) =>
                        <li key={index}>
                            <span className="mdl-layout-title menuHeader">{module.moduleName}</span>
                                {module.screens.map((screen) =>
                                    <MenuItem key={screen.id}
                                              id={screen.id}
                                              screenName={screen.screenName}
                                              icon={screen.icon}
                                              isSelected={ screen.id === this.state.selectedMenuItem ? true : false }
                                              onClick={this.onMenuItemClick}/>
                                )}
                        </li>)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Menu.propTypes = {
    modules: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
        React.PropTypes.shape({
                moduleName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                screens: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
                    React.PropTypes.shape({
                        id: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
                        screenName: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
                        icon: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
                    })
                ).isRequired
            }
        )
    ).isRequired
}
```

When I remove the ripple effect from the li tag, (mdl-js-ripple-effect class) it works fine.

What is the problem here?